# Angular 2 get current Url in protractor e2e test

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In one of my e2e tests I need to get the current url and pause the execution of the test until I get it. This is my current code:

```
let publicUrl;
browser.wait(()=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url)=>{
    publicUrl = url;
  })
});
console.log(publicUrl);
```

But `publicUrl` is always undefined as the `console.log()` line gets executed before the value has been set. I've tried many combinations of `browser.wait()` and `browser.getCurrentUrl()` but with no success:

```
let publicUrl;

browser.wait(()=>{
  return browser.getCurrentUrl()
}).then((url) => {
  publicUrl = url;
});

console.log(publicUrl);
```

I am pretty sure this must be possible, so not sure what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that uses the **.then()** is an [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) function. Your **console.log()** and its current positioning in your code is [synchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript), meaning that it will execture before the **.getCurrentUrl()** will return the value. Your code must look like this:

```
let publicUrl;
browser.wait(()=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url)=>{
    publicUrl = url;
    return console.log(publicUrl);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[GoLGo13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623572/golgo13) is Right. 
I want to add one more line that if you know, your expected url, then
you can wait for particular url.

First define your expected Url in public url;

```
let publicUrl=yourExpectedUrl;
browser.wait(()=>{
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url)=>{
    return url==publicUrl;
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`const test = await browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();`

This works perfect if you need to add a url to check certain asset url etc.

Reference: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5154#issuecomment-667656260